# I want to fetch the data between start_time and end_time using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch the data from the table with the current date and between start_time and the end_time

My table structure is like this

```
id    questions       answers    start_date      start_time     end_date      end_time

01     Testing?       Testing    2021-08-14      15:30:00       2021-08-14    17:00:00
```

and my query is

```
$arr["questions"] = questions::whereDate('start_date','=', date('Y-m-d'))
                            ->whereDate('start_time','>=', now()->format('H:i:s'))
                            ->whereDate('end_time','<=', now()->format('H:i:s'))->first();


select * from `questions` where date(`start_date`) = '2021-08-14' and date(`start_time`) >= '16:50:45' and date(`end_time`) <= '16:50:45' limit 1
```

This query not giving anything. I don't know what is the issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: You have >= for both start and end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, the start_time is greater than current time and end_time is also greater than current time. You'll need to change the operator in query of end_time. The end_time should be less than or equal to current time. You can use this in your query.

`whereDate('end_time','<=', now()->format('H:i:s'))`

**updated answers (using database query builder)**:
unfortunately, we have made a mistake while checking the time. The current_time should be greater than or equal to start_time and the current_time should be less than or equal to end_time. here is the updated query

```
$current_time = now()->format('H:i:s');
$questions = DB::table('questions')
    ->whereDate('start_date', '=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereTime('start_time', '<=', $current_time)
    ->whereTime('end_time', '>=', $current_time) ->first();
dd($questions);
```

Comment: $arr["questions"] = questions::whereDate('start_date','=', date('Y-m-d'))
                            ->whereDate('start_time','>=', now()->format('H:i:s'))
                            ->whereDate('end_time','<=', now()->format('H:i:s'))->first();

Comment: I try this also not giving any results

Comment: I think, your current time is not in between start_time and end_time and that is the reason you are not getting any result.

Comment: select * from `questions` where date(`2021-08-14`) = '2021-08-14' and date(`15:30:00`) >= '17:03:45' and date(`17:05:00`) <= '17:03:45' limit 1

Comment: Like this in my table and my current time passes the 17:05:00 result should be empty

Comment: You'll need to use mysql Time function instead of date function while you are searching data between time range. since laravel doesn't have any whereTime method so, you'll need to use whereRaw method and inside that method, you need to write the raw query.

Comment: If possible can you write and show the query

Comment: You can use database query builder to solve this issue:
`
$questions = DB::table('questions')
                ->whereDate('start_date', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
                ->whereTime('start_time', '>=', now()->format('H:i:s'))
                ->whereTime('end_time', '<=', now()->format('H:i:s'))
                ->first();
`

Comment: I tried your code also still result is null

Comment: I attached the screenshot of your query

Comment: did you check  whether your current time is in between start_time and end_time?

Comment: Yes I checked 
Table start_time = 15:00:00  end_time = 17:58:00

current time is now = 17:56:00

Comment: table start_time = 15:30:00   end_time = 18:05:00

select * from `questions` where start_date = '2021-08-14' and start_time >= '18:03:49' and end_time <= '18:03:49' limit 1

Comment: unfortunately, we have made a mistake while checking the time. The current_time should be greater than or equal to start_time and the current_time should be less than or equal to end_time. here is the updated query, please check: 
$current_time = now()->format('H:i:s');
$questions = DB::table('questions')
        ->whereDate('start_date', '=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->whereTime('start_time', '<=', $current_time)
        ->whereTime('end_time', '>=', $current_time)
        ->first();
    dd($questions);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236000/discussion-between-zahid-hassan-alvi-and-jerad).